# How to group data into already known centers of clusters in R?

Tags: r

I have a table of GPS data and I need to associate each record to the closest from a list of locations.  It's like doing clustering but I already have the centers of the clusters.

In this case the centers are latitude, longitude pairs.

Comment: This is called classification and you could use a wide range of algorithms for this, e.g. `knn`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually:

```
> f = data.table(dots = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 90, 901, 56, 1)); centers = c(6, 7)
> f[, closest := max.col(matrix(1 / abs(rep(dots, length(centers)) - rep(centers,
each = length(dots))), ncol = length(centers)))]
> f
   dots closest
1:    5       1
2:    6       1
3:    7       2
4:    8       2
5:   90       2
6:  901       2
7:   56       2
8:    1       1
```

Comment: Thanks dmitry! In this case centers are defined by latitude,longitude and so is the data.  How can I define the table and the function for the distance in that case?

Comment: @RaulVerdesia You need a function relating longitude/latitude coordinates to distance. This is actually nontrivial, depending on the particulars of your problem and operating environment. How far apart are the points? How accurate does your solution need to be?

Comment: The points to classify are in the range of 10 km but they are going to be just 10's of meters away from their respective center.